# Change font-weight of CSS `content` property

Tags: css, gradient

I need to change the font weight of part of a CSS3 content selector. Just part, not the whole thing. Here's how my code is set up:

HTML: `<p id="first-second"><a href="#"><strong>FIRST</strong> SECOND</a></p>`

CSS: `p#first-second:after {content: "FIRST SECOND"}`

I'm using [this method](http://net.tutsplus.com/tutorials/html-css-techniques/quick-tip-pure-css-text-gradients/) of creating a gradient on text.

If possible, I'd like to solve this with CSS, even if it's hacky. As you can see, the strong text is wrapped in a `<strong>` element already, and I can add IDs or classes or whatever to change it. If CSS won't fix it, then my next preference is jQuery, then JavaScript.

Comment: I'm a bit confused. What are you using generated content for if it's exactly the same as your HTML content?

Comment: To create a gradient affect with pure CSS.

Comment: I don't think generated content is a necessity for this.

Comment: `content` is neither new to CSS3 nor a selector. It's known as a property.

Comment: Wait, what are you asking? The title implies you want to adjust the font-weight of something, but the body of the question implies that it's a CSS gradient-related question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's a quick example of gradient effect applied to text using -webkit-mask-image: http://jsfiddle.net/joshvogt/t4Ger/

```
p strong{
    -webkit-mask-image: 
-webkit-gradient(linear, left top, left bottom, from(rgba(0,0,0,1)), 
to(rgba(0,0,0,0)));
    font-weight:900;
}

p{
    color:red;
    font-size:30px;
    text-shadow:2px 2px 2px black;
}
```